# The host name should not be based on already owned domain

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have downloaded the application (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-ASPNET-SSO) and ran without any issues. I have created a new Outlook add-in based on it. Followed the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2) to setup the app registration and its settings successfully.

Project runs fine and able to communicate to OneDrive, Graph from Outlook client without any issues. All good so far.

**Issue:**
The moment I am deploying the code to Azure app service and try to add the APP ID URI as my azurewebsites.net url it starts throwing issues.

**Issue 1:** If I am using azurewebsites.net url in app id url, then I cannot configure the app as multi-tenant. But, documentation says it should be configured as multi-tenant app.

**Issue 2:** If I am scoping it down to current tenant only in Authentication of app registration then it allows me to set the app id url (Expose an api) fine. But, it is failing to validate the token as it is always throwing invalid token. Outlook getaccesstoken works fine, but when I pass that token to controller, the method used in the code, ClaimsPrincipal.Current fails always.

I read here (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/40) that it might need custom domain as azurewebsites.net is not supported to prove ownership. But, I am not in a position to get custom domain for this scenario. Please let me know if anyone has workaround to this problem or need more information on the same.

I have tried to change the app to single tenant only. But, the token from Outlook client is not validated in my asp.net web api controller. It is always null

var scopeClaim = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope");

If I change the app to multi-tenant app then I can't add azurewebsites.net url to the app id url.

Comment: Have you see this? [Using SSO with an Outlook Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#using-sso-with-an-outlook-add-in). Also, why are you not in a position to create a custom domain?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "Outlook getaccesstoken"? Do you mean `Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync`? If so, what is the scope in the token that is returned by the method?

Comment: @RickKirkham Thanks for the response. I have followed the article and as I have mentioned registering localhost in reply url, app id url works fine with no issues. The moment I publish my web api project to azure (azurewebsites.net) url then issue starts as I mentioned above.

Comment: Registering custom domain my client is not allowing as they don't want to own a domain for this. And yes I am using getAccessTokenAsync and scope is mapped to acess_as_user I configured in (expose an api) in AAD registration.   "scp": "access_as_user",

Comment: You are required to use a domain that you own. If your customer will not do this, then the add-in cannot be hosted in azurewebsites.net.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by making the application single tenant instead of multi-tenant application. (It is enterprise app only for current tenant). Then changed all endpoints to map to tenant guid from /common/

All good now.